# Email subscription in android

Tags: android, email, subscription

I have a subscribe button in the about us section in my app. On pressing, a small window appears asking for email from a user. Once the user enters his email where could I store all the emails from the users? How does email subscription is implemented in Android? I'm totally new to it, so please be detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need a server where you can store in a DB the emails the clients (i.e. the apps) send you. Or since it's such a simple thing that you have to store (a string), what you could do is get them to send an email to you, and then voila, you have the addresses you need.

**EDIT:**

Try [parse](https://parse.com/), it's a cloud server free and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. It seems good enough for me. If you could add the link to your answer, I would accept it